# Calibration of Levy models and Stochastic Volatility Models - Data used

Tags: calibration

I'd like to ask a question regarding something I often come across in research papers.
It's about **how authors calibrate Levy Models and Stochastic Volatility Models to compare models' performance**, and to determine prices for exotic options like Arithmetic Asian Options.
Generally, these models are calibrated primarily with data from Vanilla option prices (when joint calibration with exotic option markets is not possible).

**My two questions are:**

**1)** Shouldn't we split the data into a training set and a testing set when evaluating how well different models fit the volatility surface?
In other words, isn't it more appropriate to use one set of data for model calibration, and another to assess how accurately the model reflects the volatility surface?

**2)** Frequently, authors do not separate the data, instead they use the whole data set for both calibration (training) and performance evaluation (testing). Why?

Thanks for considering this.

P.S. I do understand that for the only purpose of pricing exotic options, using all available data for calibration makes sense. However, my concern is about comparing the effectiveness of different models.